# On reset what happens in embedded system?

Tags: embedded, startup, reset

I have a doubt regarding the reset due to power up:

1. As I know that microcontroller is hardwired to start with some particular memory location say 0000H on power up. At 0000h, whether interrupt service routine is written for reset(initialization of stack pointer and program counter etc) or the reset address is there at 0000h(say 7000) so that micro controller jumps at 7000 address and there initialization of stack and PC is written.
2. Who writes this reset service routine? Is it the manufacturer of microcontroller chip(Intel or microchip etc) or any programmer can change this reset service routine(For example, programmer changed the PC to 4000h from 7000h on power up reset resulting into the first instruction to be fetched from 4000 instead of 7000).
3. How the stack pointer and program counter are initialized to the respective initial addresses as on power up microcontroller is not in the state to put the address into stack pointer and program counter registers(there is no initialization done till reset service routine).
4. What should be the steps in the reset service routine considering all possibilities?

Comment: are you trying to use a specific chip or board?  can you specify that chip or board?

Answer (score 5):

With reference to your numbering:

1. The hardware reset process is processor dependent and will be fully described in the data sheet or reference manual for the part, but your description is *generally* the case - different architectures may have subtle variations.
2. While some microcontrollers include a ROM based boot-loader that may contain start-up code, typically such bootloaders are only used to load code over a communications port, either to program flash memory directly or to load and execute a secondary bootloader to RAM that then programs flash memory.  As far as C runtime start-up goes, this is either provided with the compiler/toolchain, or you write it yourself in assembler.  Normally even when start-up code is provided by the compiler vendor, it is supplied as source to be assembled and linked with your application.  The compiler vendor cannot always know things like memory map, SDRAM mapping and timing, or processor clock speed or what oscillator crystal is used in your hardware, so the start-up code will generally need customisation or extension through initialisation stubs that you must implement for your hardware.
3. On ARM Cortex-M devices in fact the initial PC and stack-pointer are in fact loaded by hardware, they are stored at the reset address and loaded on power-up.  However in the general case you are right, the reset address either contains the start-up code or a vector to the start-up code, on pre-Cortex ARM architectures, the reset address actually contains a jump instruction rather than a true vector address.  Either way, the start-up code for a C/C++ runtime must at least initialise the stack pointer, initialise static data, perform any necessary C library initialisation and jump to main().  In the case of C++ it must also execute the constructors of any global static objects before calling main().

Answer (score 2):

The processor cores normally have as you say a starting address of some sort of table either a list of addresses or like ARM a place where instructions are executed.  Wrapped around that core but within the chip can vary.  Cores that are not specific to the chip vendor like 8051, mips, arm, xscale, etc are going to have a much wider range of different answers.  Some microcontroller vendors for example will look at strap pins and if the strap is wired a certain way when reset is released then it executes from a special boot flash inside the chip, a bootloader that you can for example use to program the user boot flash with.  If the strap is not tied that certain way then sometimes it boots your user code.  One vendor I know of still has it boot their bootloader flash, if the vector table has a valid checksum then they jump to the reset vector in your vector table otherwise they sit in their bootloader mode waiting for you to talk to them.

When you get into the bigger processors, non-microcontrollers, where software lives outside the processor either on a boot flash (separate chip from the processor) or some ram that is managed somehow before reset, etc.  Those usually follow the rule for the core, start at address 0xFFFFFFF0 or start at address 0x00000000,  if there is garbage there, oh well fire off the undefined instruction vector, if that is garbage just hang there or sit in an infinite loop calling the undefined instruction vector.   this works well for an ARM for example you can build a board with a boot flash that is erased from the factory (all 0xFFs) then you can use jtag to stop the arm and program the flash the first time and you dont have to unsolder or socket or pre-program anything.  So long as your bootloader doesnt hang the arm you can have an unbrickable design.  (actually you can often hold the arm in reset and still get at it with the jtag debugger and not worry about bad code messing with jtag pins or hanging the arm core).

The short answer:  How many different processor chip vendors have there been?  There are many different solutions, as many as you can think of and more have been deployed.  Placing a reset handler address in a known place in memory is the most common though.

EDIT:

Questions 2 and 3.  if you are buying a chip, some of the microcontrollers have this protected bootloader, but even with that normally you write the boot code that will be used by the product.  And part of that boot code is to initialize the stack pointers and prepare memory and bring up parts of the chip and all those good things.  Sometimes chip vendors will provide examples.   if you are buying a board level product, then often you will find a board support package (BSP) which has working example code to bring up the board and perhaps do a few things.  Say the beagleboard for example or the open-rd or embeddedarm.com come with a bootloader (u-boot or other) and some already have linux pre-installed.  boards like that the user usually just writes some linux apps/drivers and adds them to the bsp, but you are not limited to that, you are often welcome to completely re-write and replace the bootloader.  And whoever writes the bootloader has to setup the stacks and bring up the hardware, etc.

systems like the gameboy advance or nds or the like, the vendor has some startup code that calls your startup code.  so they may have the stack and such setup for them but they are handing off to you, so much of the system may be up, you just get to decide how to slice up the memorires, where you want your stack, data, program, etc.

some vendors want to keep this stuff controlled or a secret, others do not.  in some cases you may end up with a board or chip with no example code, just some data sheets and reference manuals.

if you want to get into this business though you need to be prepared to write this startup code (in assembler) that may call some C code to bring up the rest of the system, then that might start up the main operating system or application or whatever.  Microcotrollers sounds like what you are playing with, the answers to your questions are in the chip vendors users guides, some vendors are better than others.  search for the word reset or boot in the document to try to figure out what their boot schemes are.  I recommend you use "dollar votes" to choose the better vendors.  A vendor with bad docs, secret docs, bad support, dont give them your money, spend your money on vendors with freely downloadable, well written docs, with well written examples and or user forums with full time employees trolling around answering questions.  There are times where the docs are not available except to serious, paying customers, it depends on the market.  most general purpose embedded systems though are openly documented.  the quality varies widely, but the docs, etc are there.

Answer (score 1):

Depends completely on the controller/embedded system you use.  The ones I've used in game development have the IP point at a starting address in RAM.  The boot strap code supplied from the compiler initializes static/const memory, sets the stack pointer, and then jumps execution to a main() routine of some sort.  Older systems also started at a fixed address, but you manually had to set the stack, starting vector table, and other stuff in assembler.  A common name for the starting assembler file is CRT0.s for the stuff I've done.

So 1. You are correct.  The microprocessor has to start at some fixed address.
2. The ISR can be supplied by the manufacturer or compiler creator, or you can write one yourself, depending on the complexity of the system in question.
3. The stack and initial programmer counter are usually handled via some sort of bootstrap routine that quite often can be overriden with your own code.  See above.

Last: The steps will depend on the chip.  If there is a power interruption of any sort, RAM may be scrambled and all ISR vector tables and startup code should be rewritten, and the app should be run as if it just powered up.  But, read your documentation!  I'm sure there is platform specific stuff there that will answer these for your specific case.