# how first instruction is executed when the system is powered on

Tags: embedded, ram, boot, bios, rom

im very curious about how the board start up takes place ,
how the first instruction is executed when board is powered on how the peripheral are intialized...thanks in advance
how the first instruction address of ROM is loaded into PC(program counter),when system is powered on in embedded systems

Comment: If [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355798/on-reset-what-happens-in-embedded-system) is not an exact duplicate, it certainly answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

My experience is with AVR, so your mileage may vary.

Typically, the program counter starts at 0, so the first instruction is at the first position in the flash memory. This is also the location of vector table, or addresses where the processor is hardwired to jump to when interrupts of various types occur.

These addresses are only a few bytes apart, leaving only enough room for a jump instruction to somewhere else in flash. Address 0 is also the vector for the reset interrupt. That is, it is the location the processor jumps to when the reset is pressed.

The reset interrupt vector will jump to the C runtime, a bit of code added to the start of your C program. It initializes global variables in RAM and sets the stack pointer, among other things, before jumping to the main function of your code.

The vector table, the C runtime, and your code are put together by the compiler, customizing the table and runtime to fit to your code. For example, if you include an interrupt handler, a jump to it will be inserted in the vector table at the location for that type of interrupt.

There is no BIOS like on a PC. The peripherals are not automatically initialized. You have to do it in your own code for every peripheral you want to use.

Comment: As a counter-example, the 8086 will start the PC at 0xFFFF0. Basically just enough to setup some registers and jump to a more useful address.

Answer (score 1):

For something like this you can think of hardware like software just parallel.  After reset (actually during) items like the starting address and states for the state machines are initialized to the value the author wanted.  Then it starts clocking after reset and walking through the code which for a simplistic case might be address of zero state is fetch, then when the fetch ends that instruction is decoded and executed, and so on.

With respect to your question the difference between power off and normal execution is that after a power on reset, the state of the processor is put in a specific state, after that and after a while the state of the processor has to do with the code that has executed to that point.

peripheral logic works the same way but doesnt (necessarily) have a processor that runs code although some peripherals do.  then the boot code and/or operating system when it eventually runs goes out and initializes the peripherals.

Comment: This is a good generalized answer. The processor starts executing where it is designed to start. On Cortex-M ARMs, it will start at the address pointed to by 0x4. An 8086 will load PC with 0xFFFF0 (but an 8085 will load it with 0x0). An advanced system (ARM Cortex-A SoC) still does this, but the SoC's bootloader makes up the first instructions executed, and this segues into @Treesrule14's answer as to how your compiled code starts up.